# how can I prove it is a convergent sequence and how can I calculate its limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let we have the following sequence $$x_1=1$$
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2+x_n}$$  how can I prove it is a convergent sequence and how can I calculate its limit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $f(x) = \frac{1}{2 + x}$ is a strict contraction on $[0,\infty)$, indeed $|f'(x)| = \frac{1}{(2 + x)^2} \le \frac14$. Then, by the [Contraction mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), $x_{n + 1} = f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence which converges to the unique positive fixed point of $f$: $$L = \frac{1}{2 + L} \Longrightarrow L = \sqrt2 - 1.$$

Comment: Very nice, +1.$~$

Answer (score 2):

Let $L=\sqrt{2}-1$. Observe that $x_n>0$ for all $n$. Therefore

$$
\begin{align*}
|x_{n+1}-L|&=\left|\frac{1-L(2+x_n)}{2+x_n}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{L}{2+x_n}(L^{-1}-(2+x_n))\right|\\
&=\left(\frac{L}{|2+x_n|}\right)|L-x_n|\\
&\leq \frac{L}{2}|L-x_n|.
\end{align*}
$$
Since $L/2<1$, it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=L$.